# Sending Checkbox True or False in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send a bool to my `Node.js` server. Currently, what I have send a `string`. I want `bool` to send as a `bool`, not a string. To me it seems like it should be; but, in my `mongodb` database it is storing as a string. Thanks in advance!

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url",
  timeout: 2000,
  data: {
    'bool': $('input[name=bool]').is(':checked')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#Error').css('display', 'none')
    $('#Error').html('')
    $('#Good').css('display', 'block')
    $('#Good').html('Success! Sending information and redirecting...')
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    //server error
    console.log("bad server");
  }
});
```

Comment: The data you send is going to be a string, you have to convert it to bool when you receive it on the server.

Comment: @Musa - misread will delete comment. Apologies.

Comment: generally many json libraries take care of this datatype mapping internally, if no plugin is used we need to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `contentType` should allow node.js to parse the boolean:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url",
  contentType: "application/json",
  timeout: 2000,
  data: {
    'bool': $('input[name=bool]').is(':checked')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#Error').css('display', 'none')
    $('#Error').html('')
    $('#Good').css('display', 'block')
    $('#Good').html('Success! Sending information and redirecting...')
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    //server error
    console.log("bad server");
  }
});
```

Comment: Setting the content type to application/json  doesn't change the data to JSON, and you have to set up your server side code to parse the data from a string to your desired data type.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, as some of you said I needed to convert `string` to `boolean` server side. I achieved this by `var BoolName = (BoolName == bool);`. This now saves in `MongoDB` as a `boolean` type.